# Regarding factory design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was doing R&D on factory pattern I have developed the below code , please advise is it correct as per the functionality of the factory pattern..

```
    public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract String makeSound();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Woof";
    }

}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Meow";
    }

}

public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal getAnimal(String type) {
        if ("canine".equals(type)) {
            return new Dog();
        } else {
            return new Cat();
        }
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalFactory animalFactory = new AnimalFactory();

        Animal a1 = animalFactory.getAnimal("feline");
        System.out.println("a1 sound: " + a1.makeSound());

        Animal a2 = animalFactory.getAnimal("canine");
        System.out.println("a2 sound: " + a2.makeSound());
    }

}
```

Please advise it is correct as per the design of factory pattern, Can I improve it further

Comment: R&D?  Don't you just have to read the GoF book?  Looks fine...

Comment: I would call the factory method `createAnimal` instead of `getAnimal`, because that's what it does.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass in the class name you can avoid the type check:

```
public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal getAnimal(String className) throws Exception {
        Class animalClass = Class.forName(className);              
        return animalClass.newInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: @duffymo..could you please show in full code as I have done above that will make understanding more clear, thanks

Comment: @duffymo..please explain in full code as there changes also need to be done in main class too.

Comment: I did give you full code.  Figure it out.  If you can't manage it for this simple example, you should not be writing patterns - or Java, for that matter.

Comment: Yeah but please suggest what changes need to be bring out in the main file .

Comment: Just change the string that you pass to the factory to the name of the class (e.g. Dog or Cat, fully resolved with package prefix.)

Comment: 16 questions and you've accepted NONE.  Why should anyone bother to help you?